# if $a\cong b\pmod m$ prove $(a,m)=(b,m)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, congruences, gcd-and-lcm

This question gives one info which is $a\cong b \pmod m$ then we have to conclude that $(a,m)=(b,m)$. 
Here is what I have so far

$a \cong b \pmod m$ so $a-b=mj$ so $a=mj+b$ , $b=a-mj$

also let $(a,m)=d_1$ and $(b,m)=d_2$ so 
$ax+my=d_1c$ and $au+mv=d_2k$

I did some algebra and got 
$$m(jx+y-uj)+bx+au=d_2k+d_1c$$
I am stuck here....
Any hints will be greatly useful

Answer (score 1):

$a = b+mj $

Let $d1=\gcd (a,m) $ and $d2=\gcd (b,m)$.

$d1$ divides $m$. And $d1$ divides $a$.  So $d1$ divides $a - mj =b$.  So $d1$ divides $b$.  And as $d1$ divides $m$ we know $d1$ is a common divisor of $b$ and $m$.  Now $d2$ is the GREATEST common divisor of $b$ and $m$ so by definition $d2 \ge d1$.

Likewise $d2 $ divides $b+mj=a $ and so $d2$ is a common divisor of $a $ and $m $.  So $d1 \ge d2$.

So $d1=d2$.

Comment: Thank you so much!, I followed that d1|a-mj which is d|b but how d1 is a common divisor of b and m ? and how come d2>or equal to d1? I just need little clarification

Comment: @Hanan Ibraheim You know already that $d1$ divides $b$ and by definition of $d1$, $d1$ divides $m$. So, $d1$ is a common divisor of $b$ and $m$. But $d2$ is the gcd of $b$ and $m$ and hence, $d1$ divides $d2$. Because $d1$ and $d2$ are $\geq 1$, we get $d1\leq d2$.

Comment: so we can use the same linear combination that represents b to say that d1|a-mj , i mean letter wise we used j twice is that fine? I am sorry I am not able to explain what I mean

Comment: By the way, since $d1$ divides $d2$, $$\frac{d2}{d1}=k\in\Bbb N$$ which shows that $$\frac{d2}{d1}\geq 1.$$

Comment: @ΘΣΦ GenSan Thank you so much that makes so much sense!

Comment: You are the one who came up with $a = mj +b$ so $b = a- mj$.  But the $j$ isnt important.  I'd have simply said $a = b + mj$ and $b = a + km$.  We can solve for $k$ and discover that $k = -j$ but that's completely irrelevant.

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Actually, I was avoiding using the fact that if $k|m,n$ then $k|\gcd(n,m)$ in case that hadn't been a proven result yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy if you use the following characterization of the greatest common divisor.

> $d\ge 0$ is the greatest common divisor of the integers $x$ and $y$ if and only if
>
> 1. $d\mid x$ and $d\mid y$;
> 2. for every integer $e\ge0$, if $e\mid x$ and $e\mid y$, then $e\mid d$.

<sub>This has the advantage that *no* hypothesis whether $x$ and $y$ are zero is necessary.</sub>

Let $d=\gcd(a,m)$ and write $b=a+mk$. Then $d\mid a$ and $d\mid m$, so clearly $d\mid(a+mk)$, hence $d\mid b$.

Suppose $e\mid b$ and $e\mid m$. Then $e\mid a$, because $a=b-mk$. Therefore $e\mid d$, by the fact $d=\gcd(a,m)$.

Hence $d=\gcd(b,m)$.